# C# How do i find the last UNIQUE letter inside a string, and get its index?

Tags: c#

below is the Method I am trying to solve.....

```
public int IndexOfLastUniqueLetter(string str)
```

I have not tried any code yet because I have no Idea how to solve it.

Please advise how to solve this method and the code which to do so. Please and thank you.

Comment: What is a 'unique letter'? One that only exists once in the text? If so then you need to work out _which_ letters only occur once, find their index in the text, and choose the highest.

Comment: You still need to try *something*... You have a perfectly good method signature right there. Start walking though what steps you'd need to accomplish this on paper if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm boils down to these two steps:

- Find which letters are unique,
- Find the last of these unique letters in the original string.

Counting occurrences of each letter could be done with a loop, or with an associative container, depending on your preferences. If count is `1`, the letter is unique; otherwise, it is not unique. Finding last-of could be done by walking the string backward.

The only thing to worry about here is what to do when there are no unique letters in the string (e.g. `"aaaa"` or `"abab"`). Your code should detect this condition explicitly, and return `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to parse twice the string.

I personally used `a Dictionary<char, int>` which is storing the occurrence for any character in my string.

Once parsed, and because Dictionary **does not** preserve order, you can (as dasblinkenlight) mentioned parse your string backward.

Below is my method:

```
int GetIndexOfLastUniqueOccurrence(string msg)
{
    var occurrenceChar = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    // Parse the string to count occurrence
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
    {
        if (occurrenceChar.ContainsKey(msg[i]))
            occurrenceChar[msg[i]]++;
        else
            occurrenceChar.Add(msg[i], 1);
    }

    // Parse backward the string to find the last one with occurrence == 1
    for (int i = msg.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var occurrence = occurrenceChar[msg[i]];
        if (occurrence == 1)
            return i;
    }

    return -1; // If string does not contain any unique char
    }
```

Below are some tests:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetIndexOfLastUniqueOccurrence("abcddeeff")); // 2
Console.WriteLine(GetIndexOfLastUniqueOccurrence("aaaaaabbbbbcccc")); // -1
Console.WriteLine(GetIndexOfLastUniqueOccurrence("abcdefgg")); // 5
```

**Something less verbose**

If you want to create your dict out of the string using LINQ:

```
var occurrenceChar = msg.GroupBy(c => c).Select(c => new { Char = c.Key, Count = c.Count() }).ToDictionary(x => x.Char, x => x.Count);
```

**Something even less verbose** (inspired by @Jawad anwser):

```
return message.IndexOf(
            message
                .Distinct()
                .Reverse()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => message.Count(y => y.Equals(x)) == 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help WilliamW your code helped a lot and passes all the test thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I can help

Answer (score 0):

If i may suggest a single line of code,

1. Get a list of all unique letters
2. Iterate through backwards to see which one occurs only once in the string.
3. Return the index of that letter (-1 if it doesnt exist)

```
    public static int IndexOfLastUniqueLetter(string original)
    {
        return original.IndexOf(
                        original.Distinct()
                                .Reverse()
                                .Where(x => original.Where(y => y.Equals(x)).Count() == 1)
                                .FirstOrDefault());
    }
```